# Convert WCF .svc file to .asmx file

Tags: wcf, web-services, asmx, visual-c++

I have a WCF Service. I have an external software that can read *only .asmx files*. Is it possible to *convert my .svc file in the corresponding .asmx*?

Answer (score 2):

I think converting from wcf to asmx isn't very straight forward as you would be essentially going back in time with technologies. I'd image the easiest option to go for would be to write an asmx webservice which exposes the same methods as your wcf service and acts as a proxy to the wcf service.

This way your external software can call the asmx service, but also anything new can consume the wcf service. This way you can keep the logic in one place, but both benefit from updates etc.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

"Software that only reads .asmx files" doesn't make sense. No software reads either .asmx files or .svc files - both types are interpreted on the server and never returned to a client.

I think you need to look more deeply into what this external software really wants. It would be entirely brain dead if it cared about the file type in a URL!

Comment: +1 Agreed, surely the service is concerned with the protocol.

Answer (score 2):

Why to convert, keep both wcf(.svc) as well as web service (.asmx)
just follow the steps .

1. go to your WCF Project , Right Click and add new item and select Web Service (.asmx) file and expand that new file and delete inner File and just keep .asmx file .
2. open that .asmx file you will find
           `<%@ WebService Language="C#" Debug="true"    Class="{full name of web service class}" %>`

Replace it with

```
<%@ WebService Language="C#" Debug="true" Class="full name of wcf class(.cs file not interface)" %>
```

3. Last Step add service contract , web service and web service binding Attribute on interface as describe below

   [ServiceContract(Namespace = "namespacename")]
     [WebService(Name = "wcf class name")]
     [WebServiceBinding(Name = "wcf class name", ConformsTo = WsiProfiles.BasicProfile1_1,  EmitConformanceClaims = true)]

and also add web method attribute on each method declaration  of your interface.

that's it, now you can expose to file 
.asmx file for web service clients 
.svc for WCF clients

thank you

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing the external software is actually reading the WSDL generated by the asmx file, and doesn't support the protocols exposed. Definitely check what level SOAP support this software has, and adjust your wcf service accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

If the service is small, its not terribly hard.

Its possible to decorate a class with both WCF and ASMX attributes. Then reference the class in an ASMX file and a WCF file.