# Activation of Unity Dependency Injection for ASMX services

Tags: unity-game-engine, wcf, inversion-of-control, asmx

I implemented Unity.WCF for dependency injection in a WCF service of the SVC type. To activate it, I only needed to add the "Factory" attribute to the markup of my service:

```
<%@ ServiceHost Language="C#" Debug="true" 
    Service="MyNameSpace.MyService" 
    Factory="MyNameSpace.IoC.WcfServiceFactory"
    CodeBehind="MyService.svc.cs" %>
```

Now I am trying to do the same in an ASMX service. In this case the markup does not support the attribute "Factory", so I tried to activate my customized ServiceHostFactory through the web.config. I tried different configurations but I do not manage to make it work.

```
<serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true">
    <serviceActivations>
        <add factory="Service.Web.IoC.WcfServiceFactory" 
             relativeAddress="./MyWebservice.asmx" 
             service="MyNamespace.MyWebservice"/>
    </serviceActivations>
</serviceHostingEnvironment>
```

Where can I find an example how this should be done?

Answer (score 0):

The ServiceHostFactory is used for hosting in IIS. You can refer to [Inversion of Control with WCF and Unity](https://weblogs.asp.net/fabio/inversion-of-control-with-wcf-and-unity) and [Unity dependency injection for WCF services](https://www.neovolve.com/2010/05/15/unity-dependency-injection-for-wcf-services-e28093-part-1/) for help.

Comment: Thanks @Jiayao. I edited my question to make it more accurate. The websites you shared apply to wcf services. There it works fine because the configuration is done via markup in the .svc file or in the web.config serviceActivations section. But I do not find how to do this in asmx.

Comment: Maybe you can try the method in [this case](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/552977/convert-wcf-svc-file-to-asmx-file).

Comment: So your suggestion is to convert the ASMX service to a WCF so that I can activate the DI, and then add an asmx file for backwards compatibility? I'll try this approach. My only concern about it is if it will change the soap envelope, because this change should be transparent to the user. I'm going to try. Thanks.